# Behavior of ECHO command and variable definition in Unix

Tags: unix, echo

Can't post the image directly yet, so here's a link to it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl277.png

I'm trying to learn some basic unix file scripting for an Informatica project I'm working on. I've used a few scripts in the past and have only a very rudimentary idea of what to do so I'm just playing around with the various parts of an existing script.

I can't make heads or tails of some of the behavior of the commands. Here is an example using ECHO. The thing appears to just randomly return one of: the variable I defined, the variable name, or an error.

e.g. why does:

> $ _Src="/home/axxxxxx"
>   $ echo "${_Src}"

return

> /home/axxxxxx

but

> $ INFA_HOME="/home"
>   $ echo "${INFA_HOME}"

returns

> ksh: "${INFA_HOME_^H}": bad substitution

other inscrutable behavior:

> $ echo "${INFA_HOME} now"
>    >
>   $ echo "${INFA_HOME} now"
>   /home now
>   $ echo "${INFA_HOME} "
>   {INFA_HOME}
>   $ echo "${INFA_HOME} now"
>   /home now

Answer (score 0):

Likely because the script actually contains echo "${INFA_HOME_<kbd>backspace</kbd>}"